# How to check variable type using “type” function in Sikuli

Tags: python, jython, sikuli, built-in

Sikuli has its own function *type* for typing. Is there any way to invoke python (jython) function *type*? Module *builtins* can’t be imported. Of course I can use *isinstance* instead but I am just curious if it is possible to come outside Sikuli scope and invoke not “overridden”, python built-in *type* function. I use Sikuli r930.

```
#import builtins                         #ImportError: No module named builtins
findAll("1369036502514.png")
matches = getLastMatches()
print(isinstance(matches,Finder))        #returns TRUE
type("1369035684637.png",'hello world')  #types characters 
type('hello world again')                #types characters 
print(type(matches))                     #TypeError: type(): 1st arg can't be coerced to String
```

Running *builtins.type* results in failure too:

```
builtins.type(matches)
NameError: name 'builtins' is not defined

__builtins__.type(matches)
NameError: name '__builtins__' is not defined
```

Comment: The answer can be found on this page (solved by RaiMan): https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/794880

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `matches.__class__`.